# Where is the entry point in the file system to open a MEAN stack site?

Tags: mean-stack, lamp, environment

For a LAMP website hosted on your localhost server, you would simply open index.html or index.php of the website in a browser to run the site.

Where is the entry point to open a sample website using the MEAN stack?

I've loaded a copy of this repository https://github.com/linnovate/mean into a www/var/ directory, to see if I could get a MEAN site working. In attempting to access 
/mean-master/packages/custom/meanStarter/public/views/system/index.html.
It fails to open "403 Forbidden".
I am using Ubuntu 16-LTS with Eclipse, I believe I have the appropriate dependencies but I still might be approaching this all wrong.

My goal is to get a sample MEAN stack site running on my localhost and explore from there.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "entry point" - for a LAMP website, you configure the default pages (index.html, index.php, etc.) in Apache's .htaccess file. Are you asking about the default pages for MEAN stack? Or are you asking where the website's root directory is located by default? According to the tutorial you should be able to just open http://localhost:3000 once installed, did you have trouble with that?

Comment: I'm making an analogy. For a LAMP-stack site,  you simply open the index.html once you've setup your Apache server.  What is the equivalent procedure for launching the homepage of a MEAN-stack website? I'm not sure if I can edit the original question for clarity, I'm rather new to using stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the `node server` command which will start the node web app contained in the server.js file. Basically server.js is the starting point.

In the readme itself it explains how to start it : https://github.com/linnovate/mean#invoke-node-with-a-task-manager